# Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Menu adding Weird arrows on Dropdown

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I don't understand why this is happening with my responsive twitter bootstrap nav. Here's a screenshot:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/79b436f8-822c-4fdc-ad36-a1d706686d05/3a735fc948474e109c08b773f01f0cf8

It's adding those weird arrows that point up. The carets are intended and those are ok. It goes away if I remove all of the `dropdown` classes from the `<li class="dropdown">`. But doing that breaks the nav. Otherwise the nav is working great. Here's my markup:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <%= link_to "Tip Share", root_path, :class => "brand" %>

      <div class="nav-collapse">

                <ul class="nav pull-left">
                    <% if current_user %>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#"class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Sales
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                          </a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><%= link_to "New Sales", new_sale_path  %></li>
                                <li><%= link_to "Manage Sales", sales_path  %></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Shifts
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                          </a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><%= link_to "New Shift", new_shift_path %></li>
                                <li><%= link_to "Manage Shifts", shifts_path %></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Employees
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                          </a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><%= link_to "New Employee", new_employee_path %></li>
                                <li><%= link_to "Manage Employees", employees_path %></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Positions
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                          </a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><%= link_to "New Position", new_position_path %></li>
                                <li><%= link_to "Manage Positions", positions_path %></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <% if current_user %>
                        <li>
                        <%= link_to root_path do %>
                        <%= current_user.email %>
                    <% end %>
                    </li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'Log out', logout_path %></li>
                    <% else %>
                    <li><%= link_to 'Sign up', signup_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'Log in', login_path  %></li>
                  <% end %>
                </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems like there's nothing wrong with this markup, but I keep getting these little arrows. I'd rather figure what I'm doing wrong with bootstrap than try to override it with css

How do I get rid of these arrows?

FYI, I'm using the bootstrap-sass gem to import twitter bootstrap.

Comment: In chrome try right clicking on that arrow and inspect element.

Comment: Right, I did that, the problem is that it's applied to a psuedo selector so I can't select it in chrome. I found out where it's happening now and I think the real issues is my media query specific styles are not showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding .navbar-inner gives it enough specificity to work:

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .navbar .navbar-inner .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
      display: none;
    }
}/* end media query */
```

But, I find it weird that the rule that is included in Boostrap by default doesn't work:

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the real issue is that my media query specific styles are not working. This is actually built into boostrap:

```
/* line 112, ../../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@tips/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.1.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_responsive-navbar.scss */
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:before,
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:after {
    display: none;
  }
```

But that style is not being recognized even though my browser is well below 979px:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/229f1ad6-99eb-4659-8e27-28950e9eb1db/36b7738b5c45a8d439dd39ef39fb5c77

So it appears to be an issue with bootstrap media queries that doesn't make sense. I wonder if this has something to do with the asset pipeline in rails.

---

Update:

Adding this fixes it:

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
      display: none !important;
    }

}/* end media query */
```

But that `!important` is really bad. Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong that would cause this inheritance problem in my css.